# Installing 13.04 Server on Hardware raid 0. Fails to install grub on /dev/mapper

Tags: installation, server, grub2, raid

I am installing 13.04 Server using guided setup. It is going on a hardware raid 0. Everything is working swell until I get to where I need to install grub.

It gives examples of /dev/sda and /dev/sdb and such.
Since it is a raid 0 is has defaulted to /dev/mapper
Reading other questions it seems I need to complete this with /dev/mapper/
How do I find this raid name?

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually have a hardware raid.  You have what is known as a [Fake Raid](http://wiki.ubuntu.com/FakeRaidHowto), which is really just a bad software raid implemented in the bios and a special driver for Windows.  If you don't need to dual boot with Windows, you should avoid using it since Linux software raid is much better supported and feature complete.

Your actual question is unclear.  The list box of where to install grub to will have /dev/mapper/something in it, and that is where you need to install it to.